# GUI Git client for Windows: SourceTree VS GitEye

Tags: windows, git, user-interface, client

I am currently using SourceTree as my GUI Git client for Windows but have recently found out about the existence of GitEye.

I would like to find out which one you use, would recommend, and why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @devnull I have found no question similar to this one. Also, since it is really closely related to coding, I don't think it belongs to any other StackExchange. And last but not least, I think this is an interesting question, at least for me to know what are the reasons to use one or another tool, and I bet more people want to know.